# UIView disappears and shows nothing when connected with GADBannerView Admob

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I added AdMob bannerView in my iOS application. I followed there online Firebase tutorial but when I connect my UIView with GADBannerview class, view disappears on running and shows nothing. I also added my device as test device.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  //Add a AdMob banner with Unit ID.
  self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"MyAdMobUnitID";
  self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
  GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
  request.testDevices = @[
                        @"MyTestDeviceID"  //iPhone6
                        ];
  [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
  [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The bannerView size must be 320x50. I am landscape layout therefore, I was using larger size. After correcting size to 320x50, it starts working. :)